# Android: How to start video activity on portrait mode

Tags: android, android-video-player

I am trying to play video from url using the following code:

```
Intent intent= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(movieurl), "video/*");
startActivity(intent);
```

When I intent started it show the video player in landscape mode is it possible to set it to portrait mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That functionality is provided by the videoplayer. The videoplayer has been set to show video in landscape mode..U can use videoview and mediacontroller to create your own media player.