# Set the orientation of the screen when activity started through code

Tags: android, media-player

How to change my code so that the orientation is always Portrait in the activity being started...Now it is landscape. (Ps:I searched in the net..no much use.)

```
final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                        Intent viewMediaIntent = new Intent();   
                        viewMediaIntent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);   
                        viewMediaIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(schedule.getRecordPath()), "audio/*");   
                        viewMediaIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

                        v.getContext().startActivity(viewMediaIntent);
```

Comment: --follow this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6353444/android-how-to-start-video-activity-on-portrait-mode

Comment: @AndroidRevolution... Thanks android revolution...That worked

Answer (score 0):

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_PORTRAIT);
```

Comment: In start of  `onCreate()` method after the supper is called.